# Nltk naive bayesian classifier memory issue

Tags: python, nltk, bayesian, classification

my first post here!
I have problems using the nltk NaiveBayesClassifier. I have a training set of 7000 items. Each training item has a description of 2 or 3 worlds and a code. I would like to use the code as label of the class and each world of the description as features.
An example:

"My name is Obama", 001
...

Training set = {[feature['My']=True,feature['name']=True,feature['is']=True,feature[Obama]=True], 001}

Unfortunately, using this approach, the training procedure NaiveBayesClassifier.train use up to 3 GB of ram..
What's wrong in my approach?
Thank you!

```
def document_features(document): # feature extractor
document = set(document)
return dict((w, True) for w in document)

...
words=set()
entries = []
train_set= []
train_length = 2000
readfile = open("atcname.pl", 'r')
t = readfile.readline()
while (t!=""):
  t = t.split("'")
  code = t[0] #class
  desc = t[1] # description
  words = words.union(s) #update dictionary with the new words in the description
  entries.append((s,code))
  t = readfile.readline()
train_set = classify.util.apply_features(document_features, entries[:train_length])
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set) # Training
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `nltk.classify.apply_features` which returns an object that acts like a list but does not store all the feature sets in memory.

`from nltk.classify import apply_features`

More Information and a Example [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html)

You are loading the file anyway into the memory, you will need to use some form of lazy loading method. Which will load as per need basis. 
Consider looking into [this](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.util.LazyMap-class.html)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I tried but i dont have some improvement in memory usage. Using train_set = classify.util.apply_features(document_features, entries[:1500]), with only 1500 items, i use 1.7GB....

Comment: Can you post a gist of your train set and the exact syntax you are trying to use. apply_features works typically very well.