# Python nltk ~ Handling many features with naivebayes without getting MemoryError or ValueError?

Tags: python, memory, nltk

I have many short sentences with an associated label (that I want to predict). For example:

```
This is a short sentence, label1
```

For each of the short sentences, I am extracting all of the nouns and adjectives and using them as features for a naive bayes classifier. So for the sentence above:

```
short, sentence
```

Are the two words that would be extracted.

## **How many features?**

In total I have 260,000 observations (50 MB csv file). From this I am able to extract about 7,103 unique nouns and adjectives. But using them all is just impractical. So I want to use the top **N** most frequently occuring words as features.

If I use the top 50 words my code runs just fine. Here is a snippet:

```
featuresets   = [(document_features(i), i.label) for i in y]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[testTrainCutoff:], featuresets[:testTrainCutoff]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

## **Problem**

If use the top 100 words though, I get 'MemoryError' when trying to build 'featuresets'. From another question on stackoverflow, I found a potential solution which was to "use `nltk.classify.apply_features` which returns an object that acts like a list but does not store all the feature sets in memory" ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723875/nltk-naive-bayesian-classifier-memory-issue/9724855#9724855)).

So I updated my code:

```
train_set, test_set = y[testTrainCutoff:], y[:testTrainCutoff]
train_set, test_set = apply_features(document_features,train_set), apply_features(document_features,test_set)
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

However, now I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py", line 191, in train
for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

As a side note: I am running this on a 40 GB RAM machine, so I find it odd that I am getting these errors

Comment: Using the most frequently occurring words as features is a bad idea. Those are typically the non-discriminative words (stop words, function words). Also 7k features isn't very much for text classification.

Comment: larsmans, true; I would ideally like to include all 7k features, and on a 40 GB RAM machine I thought I would be able to, but even with 100 features, I get memoryError. NaiveBayes assumes independence, so all the classifier has to do is tabulate counts for each of the features and the different labels. So I am not sure why I am hitting a MemoryError.

Comment: NLTK wasn't designed to work at that scale. It's a teaching toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue, and for me it was not related to system resources. Here is the solution for my case.

I was populating my feature object as as dict of features:

```
features = {<features>}
```

instead of as a tuple containing a dict and a classification value:

```
features = ({<features>},classification)
```

No matter how small I made the feature array, it always gave me

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

with this incorrect data structure. Once I changed to a tuple, everything worked fine. Hope this helps.